# Exporting DXF in 1:1 Scale

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, export, scale, dxf

I'm trying to export a parcel map as a DXF to scale. Initially I was having issues because my projection was set to WGS 84. I looked through questions on GIS Stack Exchange and learned that I needed to switch to a local projection that is designed for imperial units (US feet).

When I set my projection to NAD83 / California Zone 5 (ftUS), it brought me closer to where I needed to be, but it was still not at 1:1 scale. I have no issues scaling it up using a google map reference, but I was wondering if there was a better workflow for this type of scenario.

I'm using MacArthur Park in Los Angeles as a reference (one side measuring ~1,544 ft. on QGIS but it comes into AutoCAD as 127 ft.)

Answer (score 1):

Check the format of the parcel map you are starting with.

With that 12:1 measurement, your AutoCAD drawing is in inches (architectural) units.